# Table view double cell separator is coming in 6s

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

in my table view, double cell separator appears in 6s but not in 5
[image]

[image]

i think it is an issue regarding the ios version, i have done google search but no results were found.
i am not able to figure it out please help

This is what it shows in 6s when i have given

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

[image]

Comment: have you check with full screen mode of simulator ? by clicking of Command + 1

Comment: Check on device or zoom it and check it

Comment: yes sir i have run it in my phone also and it appears the same

Comment: both in 4s or 5 and 6s

Comment: are you check in simulator or device.

Comment: i have checked this in both

Comment: and even though i have make the cell separator style equal to none then also it shows in my 6s but in 4s it is not